# IP3000 Installation problems

Tags: delphi, components, installation

I am attempting to install the IP3000 components into my Delphi 6 environment.
I figured I'd see if any of you have had experience getting it installed. From the files I have, there seems to be an installer missing (I have the UNWISE.exe).

I've tried including just about every folder in the environment's library path and browsing path and then build and install the packages (.DPK) with no luck.

Unfortunately, these Tww DB aware components are interleaved throughout my project so I can't get by without this package.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you don't get a successful answer here, I would recommending contacting InfoPower Support they are typically really good a these types of things.

Comment: Ha I couldn't find their website, because I was searching for ip3000 ...sigh.

Answer (score 0):

IME, most component install problems have some variation of the word 'path': Search Path (Delphi), Library Path (Delphi), System Path (Windows).
My advice is to put the *.bpl and *.dcu generated by the compilation in a path contained
in the Windows path (if you want to have some sanity on this, get the [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com) tool to deal with the Win path - which have a system one and user env one).
After dealing with that, install again. And:

- Create a new vcl forms project
- Put a random sample of their components on the form (if you can see then on pallete)
- Press F9 to compile

So, if works, your install is complete. Don't try this with your own projects, as you can get nasty surprises when this fail....